# How do I adjust my screen resolution on my HP mini?

Tags: windows-7, display

Firefox displays resolution unsupported when I attempt to view a mail. How do I adjust my screen resolution?

Comment: View a mail? What do you mean? Firefox is a web browser, not an email client...

Answer (score 1):

Most programs will support dynamic zooming.  If you hold down the Ctrl Key and scroll the mouse wheel you can zoom in.  An alternative is ctrl and minus or plus. Window Key and NumPad Minus also brings up the Windows magnifier, which magnifies where ever your mouse pointer is.